# Assigning reference to temp object c++ visual

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I noticed in visual studio for c++ whenever I run code like

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 

int &test() {
    int num = 19;
    return num;
}

int main() {
    auto &num = test();
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

Which obviously shouldnt work cause num is a local object in test but some how it compiles on visual studio. Also this code compiles

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "eyyy";

    std::string str2 = "jgasgs";

    std::string &c = str1 + str2;

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Which shouldnt work cause it assigns a normal reference to a temp object.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "gs";

    std::string str2 = "a";

    std::string &c = str1 + str2;

    std::cout << &(str1 + str2) << std::endl;
}
```

In here it shouldnt let me do it because str1 + str2 should make a temp and you can't use address of a temp. When I searched it up showshttps://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807118/temporary-objects-can-be-bound-to-non-const-references which sais put warning 4 on but even when I do it still works so why does this work and how do I fix it? Also in the first example it doesnt work with strings and throws a exception, the second one only works with strings and the third also only works with strings.

Comment: Warnings do not prevent the compilation of your program. Your program will compile, but it might not run correctly.

Comment: I know but why does it give error for some types and no error for others?

Comment: In the second and third example it only works with the string type and in the first one when I try to returrn a string it throws a runtime error

Comment: Read what I wrote again.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ 11 there is a new feature called "Object life extension". And it depends on the context.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

"Lifetime of a temporary
Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a base subobject of a temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference, with the following exceptions:
a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of the return expression. Such function always returns a dangling reference.
a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696)
(until C++14)
a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference.
a temporary bound to a reference in the initializer used in a new-expression exists until the end of the full expression containing that new-expression, not as long as the initialized object. If the initialized object outlives the full expression, its reference member becomes a dangling reference.
In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime."

Answer (score 0):

In C++, "shouldn't work" and "doesn't compile" are distinct things.

In particular, warnings emitted by the compiler are just that; they don't prevent compilation. Compilers usually have an option called "treat warnings as errors" that you should enable whenever possible.

Hopefully, this also catches the fact that you are returning a reference to a local variable, which is another thing that shouldn't work and yet will happily compile (and even appear to run correctly in simple cases).